# Reciving empty file objects from frontend to backend React and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to upload a file to a server send with axios. To send it I use react with Hooks and UseState, the thing is that when I do the console.log of the file in de frontend it shows all correctly but when I send it to backend I recive it empty.

Here is an example about  what shows the frontend with console.log():

[image]

Here is the function I use to send the 3 files to backend and the differents things like react Hooks and that which I need:

```js
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState("");
  const [frontPhoto, setFrontPhoto] = useState({});
  const [sidePhoto, setSidePhoto] = useState({});
  const [backPhoto, setBackPhoto] = useState({});

  const JWT = new ClassJWT();
  const axiosReq = axios.create();

  const [uploadErrors, setUploadErrors] = useState([{}]);

  const upload  = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await JWT.checkJWT();
    console.log(frontPhoto);
    axiosReq.post("http://localhost:3001/upload-progress", {
      weight,
      frontPhoto,
      sidePhoto,
      backPhoto,
      token: JWT.getToken()
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.data.statusCode === '200') {

      } else {

      }
    });
  };
```

And then, in the backend de console.log() is like this:

```
{
  weight: '70',
  frontPhoto: {},
  sidePhoto: {},
  backPhoto: {},
  token: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNjI2NTk3Mjg1LCJleHAiOjE2MjY1OTgxODV9.njDz7BZX57NvAK399abQLhoelpTS4kStj4LBzjw5gR8'
}
```

Here is the router code I use to this upload:

```js
routerProgress.post("/upload-progress", verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
}
```

And here is all the server configuration:

```js
import express from 'express';
import sequelize from './db/db.js';
import cors from 'cors';
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';

// SERVER CONFIGURATION
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at ${PORT}`);
    sequelize.sync({ force: false })
        .then(() => console.log('Database Connected!'))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
});

// BODYPARSER
app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000}));
app.use(cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true
}));
app.use(fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true
}));

// ROUTES
import { routerAuthentication } from './routes/authentication.js';
import { routerProgress } from './routes/progress.js';
app.use(routerAuthentication);
app.use(routerProgress);
```

I don't know how to solve it, I tried many things but anything doesn't word. Please if anyone know what can I do to solve it, I'll be very grateful with him. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you perform setFrontPhoto, setSidePhoto etc.? Can you show us that code?

Comment: express doesn't natively allow posting of files to the server, you have to use something like multer or express-file-upload or other middlewares like that which handle parsing files for you.